# How to parse xml response using retrofit in kotlin?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
    <photos page="1" pages="3704" perpage="100" total="370320">
        <photo id="49658592343" owner="138998919@N06" secret="0db4e03977" server="65535" farm="66" title="mmm " ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" />
        <photo id="49658586758" owner="156045424@N06" secret="2444dda679" server="65535" farm="66" title="Boeing 787-9 (G-CKOG) Norwegian Airlines" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" />
        <photo id="49659129251" owner="156045424@N06" secret="97d1bd202e" server="65535" farm="66" title="Boeing 787-9 (G-CKOG) Norwegian Airlines" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0" />
         </photos>
</rsp>
```

and I am using SimpleXmlConverterFactory as a retrofit converter .I have converted the above response to json through an online converter and created a data class from it, parent class is as follows:

```
data class ResponseImages(
    val photos: Photos,
    val stat: String
)
```

but I am getting this error everytime i run the app:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute 'stat' does not have a match in class com.abx.cbz.Response.ResponseImages at line -1
```

so what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: "stat" is an attribute, "rsp" is an element, your data class is missing required annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading various SO threads i have managed to make it work by using the following code block:

```
@Root(name = "photos")
data class Photos @JvmOverloads constructor(

    @field:Attribute(name = "page")
    @param:Attribute(name = "page")
    var page: String,

    @field:Attribute(name = "pages")
    @param:Attribute(name = "pages")
    var pages: String,

    @field:Attribute(name = "perpage")
    @param:Attribute(name = "perpage")
    var perpage: String,

    @field:ElementList(name = "photo", inline = true)
    @param:ElementList(name = "photo", inline = true)
    var photo: List<Photo>,

    @field:Attribute(name = "total")
    @param:Attribute(name = "total")
    var total: String
)
```

The same format should be used for other data classes too, I am only displaying one. There needs to be an empty constructor that's why I have used @JvmOverloads but the use of @param annotation is not that clear yet, a brief idea is we have to force Kotlin to generate constructor overloads.

Comment: param annotation defines that the Element or Attribute (defined in annotations) are the parameters of the constructor in the data class. Element list is the annotation to define an array.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has worked for me:
[serialize](https://github.com/pdvrieze/xmlutil) + [annotation](https://github.com/pdvrieze/xmlutil/blob/master/examples/README.md) + [converter](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter)

code in gradle:

```
kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.21"
...

implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:1.0.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.2")
implementation("io.github.pdvrieze.xmlutil:core:0.86.3")
implementation("io.github.pdvrieze.xmlutil:serialization:0.86.3")
```

retrofit factory:

```
val contentType = "text/xml".toMediaType()
val retro = Retrofit.Builder()
.addConverterFactory(XML.asConverterFactory(contentType))
```

annotation:

```
@Serializable
@XmlSerialName("myclass")
data class MyClass (
    @XmlElement(false)
    @XmlSerialName("id")
    var id: String = "",

    @XmlSerialName("item")
    @XmlElement(true)
    var items: List<Item> = listOf(Item())
}
```

- I tried to use fastxml in my case, it worked well in okhttp3, but without retrofit.

Unsuccessful attempts:

- SimpleXmlConverterFactory
  I couldn't serialize my classes properly. Deprecated!!!
- JaxbConverterFactory
  that JAXB does not work on Android.
- TikXML
  Work in Progress. Needed kotlin-kapt plugin. There were error whith implementation com.tickaroo.tikxml:processor (no type adaper exception)